# Variable is not defined JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, variables, var

Hi i'm pretty new to programming, and this is probably a really easy answered question but I don't know how to fix it. I am making a sort of art program that you draw with the arrow keys, I am also using sublime text 2 as my editor.

According to the dev. Console it is not defined but it looks defined to me. Anyway I looked for an answer but most of the things I saw were just people that forgot to define the variable, otherwise it was not JS, HTML.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var keysDown = {};
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
});

function update(mod) {
    if (37 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.x -= mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (38 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.y -= mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.x += mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.y += mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
}

function render() {
var img = document.getElementById("super");
ctx.drawImage(img,mySprite.x,mySprite.y);
}
function run() {
    update((Date.now() - time) / 1000);
    render();
    time = Date.now();
}

var time = Date.now();
setInterval(run, 10);
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Draw With PNGS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="800" ></canvas>
        <img id="super" src="superman.png" alt="superman" width="20" height="20">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"...According to the dev. Console it is not defined..."* ***What*** is not defined?

Comment: @PHPglue: If you're talking about the `in` operator, it converts its left operand to a string. `var o = {}; o[37]="foo"; 37 in o; // true`

Comment: You mean people that just forgot to define a variable like you forgot to define `mySprite` here?

Comment: @Harry: If you're talking about `mySprite`, I sure don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Does every variable has to have var in it? I've defined variables before like this without var. I also tried to put var in these but, it didn't work? Also I was trying to add a border to the canvas. How would I fix this? Sorry if this is a really dumb question

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on the online fiddle engine and what is missing is your `mySprite` declaration.

You need to declare the sprite globally like your `keysDown` object. So I set my sprite to `var mySprite ={speed:10, y:0, x:0};`

You need to initialize x and y and speed or you will attempt to do math with undefined values which will also set x and y to NaN (not a number).

[This is the link to the JS fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sxxxjp9w/1/)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mySprite ={speed:10, y:0, x:0};
var keysDown = {};
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
});
 
function update(mod) {
    if (37 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.x -= mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (38 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.y -= mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.x += mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.y += mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
}
 
function render() {
var img = document.getElementById("super");
ctx.drawImage(img,mySprite.x,mySprite.y);
}

function run() {
    update((Date.now() - time) / 1000);
    render();
    time = Date.now();
}
 
var time = Date.now();
setInterval(run, 10);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Draw With PNGS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="800" ></canvas>
        <img id="super" src="superman.png" alt="superman" width="20" height="20">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a problem. Best of luck!